# Batman comic where Hugo Strange trains new Robins

Tags: story-identification, comics, batman, robin, dc-elseworlds

I have a slight hunch this is an Elseworlds story. From what I can vaguely remember, Hugo Strange is Batman. He hires boys and girls to be Robins. I think this a slightly older comic maybe around 2010s or before (not sure).

Sorry for the lack of details, it has been a long time since I read it.

Note: I'm not really sure if Hugo Strange was batman. The main highlight was that there were several Robins. (not the ones we're familiar with)

Answer (score 7):

Ok...so I have found the comic that I was looking for (by chance after a long time). It turned out to be ***[Batman: Orphans](https://www.dc.com/comics/batman-orphans-2011/batman-orphans-1)*** (2011).

> Robin's been found dead! And that's not an easy thing to face – especially when you're Tim Drake! In this pre-RED ROBIN tale, Tim and Batman must solve the murder of an impostor Robin and follow the trail of someone putting together a new team of teenaged sidekicks made up of kids who've been promised that they'll become the new Robin…IF they survive!

Yeah, Hugo Strange isn't Batman in this one; there's just one scene of him claiming to be.

Answer (score 4):

The only time I can find a Hugo Strange as Batman is [Batman: Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Prey). As [noted here](https://www.ranker.com/list/who-has-been-batman-in-comics/math-erao)

> In 1990's Batman: Prey, which collects issues of Batman: Legends of the Dark Knight, Hugo Strange is introduced as a psychoanalyst profiling Batman. Eventually, his own eccentricities emerge, and Strange begins dressing up and acting as Batman.
>
> Strange technically doesn't become Batman. Instead, his stint in the cape and cowl serves as his own supervillain origin story. His mixture of genius and obsession - with the latter firmly focused on Batman - helps create one of the Dark Knight's greatest foes.

[image: Hugo Strange as Batman]

There's no mention of him hiring people as Robin(s), but he does hypnotize [Maxwell Cort](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Maxwell_Cort_(New_Earth)), and turn him into the villain Night Scourge.

Comment: I'm sorry this wasn't it. Robins were a key part of this story (that I'm looking for)